# Show all colors on colorbar with scatter plot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, scatter-plot

In the following I use scatter and an own `ListedColormap` to plot some coloured data points. In addition the corresponding `colorbar` is also plotted.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm
from numpy import arange

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

my_cm = ListedColormap(['#a71b1b','#94258f','#ea99e6','#ec9510','#ece43b','#a3f8ff','#2586df','#035e0d'])
bounds=range(8)
norm = BoundaryNorm(bounds, my_cm.N)

data = [1,2,1,3,0,5,3,4]
ret = ax.scatter(range(my_cm.N), [1]*my_cm.N, c=data, edgecolors='face', cmap=my_cm, s=50)
cbar = fig.colorbar(ret, ax=ax, boundaries=arange(-0.5,8,1), ticks=bounds, norm=norm)
cbar.ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both',length=0)
```

If my data is not covering each value of the boundary interval, the `colorbar` does not show all colours (like in the added figure). If `data` would be set to `range(8)`, I get a dot of each colour and the `colorbar` also shows all colours.

[image]

How can I force the `colorbar` to show all defined colours even if `data` does not contain all boundary values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking for something else, I found another solution to that problem: [colorbar-for-matplotlib-plot-surface-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600579/colorbar-for-matplotlib-plot-surface-command).
In that case, I do not need to set `vmin` and `vmax` and it is also working in cases if the arrays/lists of points to plot are empty. Instead a `ScalarMappable` is defined and provided to `colorbar` instead of the `scatter`instance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from numpy import arange

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

my_cm = ListedColormap(['#a71b1b','#94258f','#ea99e6','#ec9510','#ece43b','#a3f8ff','#2586df','#035e0d'])
bounds=range(8)
norm = BoundaryNorm(bounds, my_cm.N)
mappable = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=my_cm)
mappable.set_array(bounds)

data = [] # also x and y can be []
ax.scatter(x=range(my_cm.N), y=[1]*my_cm.N, c=data, edgecolors='face', cmap=my_cm, s=50)
cbar = fig.colorbar(mappable, ax=ax, boundaries=arange(-0.5,8,1), ticks=bounds, norm=norm)
cbar.ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both',length=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually set `vmin`and `vmax` in your call to `ax.scatter`:

`ret = ax.scatter(range(my_cm.N), [1]*my_cm.N, c=data, edgecolors='face', cmap=my_cm, s=50, vmin=0, vmax=7)`

resulting in

[image]

> If my data is not covering each value of the boundary interval, the colorbar does not show all colours (like in the added figure).

If either `vmin`or `vmax` are `None the color limits are set via the method
[autoscale_None](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/colors.py#L964), and the minimum and maximum of your data are therefore used.

So using your code it is actually not necessary for showing all colors in the colorbar that every value of the boundary interval is covered, only the minimum and maximum need to be included.
Using e.g. `data = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7]` results in the following:

[image]