# How to plot 3D voxels with given coordinates on a sphere using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm currently trying to make a 3D voxels plot with know coordinates on a sphere. The x, y and z coordinates are lists filtered from a CSV. Additionally I have another list with same length as x, y and z containing the color of the voxel. With these list I want to create a 3D voxel sphere.

This I already accomplished using a 3D scatter plot (matplotlib) but the result is not very clear:

```
x = []
y = []
z = []
c = []
red = (1, 0, 0, 1)
green = (0, 1, 0, 1)
blue = (0, 0, 1, 1)
black = (0, 0, 0, 1)

for i in range(len(result)):
    x.append(20 * math.sin(math.radians(90 - result[i][1])) * math.cos(math.radians(result[i][0])))
    y.append(20 * math.sin(math.radians(90 - result[i][1])) * math.sin(math.radians(result[i][0])))
    z.append(20 * math.cos(math.radians(90 - result[i][1])))
    if result[i][2] == 1000:
        c.append(black)
    elif result[i][2] > 500:
        c.append(red)
    elif 200 < result[i][2] <= 500:
        c.append(blue)
    else:
        c.append(green)

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.grid(True)
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=c, s=500)
pyplot.show()
```

[3D-Scatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nklXd.png)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not clear"? How would an ideal plot look like?

Comment: It looks like your points are arranged pretty regularly. You may be interested in [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6600579/2454357).

Comment: Ideally I would like it to look like an sphere where colors fade into each other. Something similar as in the picture from the link Thomas Kühn provided.
Indeed the point are arranged regularly but that depends on the data in the CSV, which for now is regularly.