# Julia surf with facecolor, want colorbar

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I'm looking to get a colorbar working in Julia for a surface plot with facecolors similar to this example.

[Colorbar for matplotlib plot_surface command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600579/colorbar-for-matplotlib-plot-surface-command)

In julia 0.4.3 I am using commands:

```
figure()
subplot(111,projection="3d")
surf(x,y,z,facecolors=get_cmap("jet").o(N))
```

I'm not sure how to recreate the scalarmappable solution shown, with Julia, or is there a way to have tho colorbar independent of the plot where the max and min values come from the data?

Note:  use x,y,z,N defined according to link reference above, and the .o notation for old versions of Julia was pulled from this old example 
https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/issues/418

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT!

In a separate figure window plot the flat version.
Then pull the colorbar and put it on the surface plot!

```
figure(1)
pmesh = pcolormesh(u,v,z1)

figure(2)
subplot(111,projection="3d")
surf(x,y,z,facecolors=get_cmap("jet").o(N))
colorbar(pmesh)
```

Note:  use u,v,z1,x,y,z,N defined according to first link reference in Question above