# How can i add a colorbar to display scalar values in my 3d surface plot with jupyter

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter, surface, colorbar, circuit

I have been trying to create a 3D surface plot using Matplotlib with Python3 through the Jupyter Notebook to visualise the total resistance of a circuit with 3 compontents. I have the resistance of component one, two and three on the x,y,z axis respectively and I have been trying to visualise the total resistance by assigning colours the surface. I have been able to generate the surface plot and coloured it accordingly but when I try to introduce a colour bar to the plot I run into a lot of errors. Any help to add the colour bar and label and scale it accordingly would be greatly appreciated

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import matplotlib as mpl
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
%matplotlib inline

from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

def f(r1,r2):
return (r1*r2)/(r1+r2)
r1 = np.linspace(0.001,15,100)
r2 = np.linspace(0.001,15,100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(r1,r2)
W = f(X,Y)

def g(r12,r3):
return (r12*r3)/(r12+r3)
r12 = (r1*r2)/(r1+r2)
r3 = np.linspace(0.001,15,100)
A,B = np.meshgrid(r12,r3)
Z = g(A,B)

minn, maxx = Z.min(), Z.max()
norm = colors.LogNorm(minn,maxx)
m = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap='coolwarm')
m.set_array([Z])
fcolors = cm.coolwarm(Z)

surf = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,B, rstride=1,cstride=1,
               facecolors=fcolors, vmin=minn,vmax=maxx, shade=False)
pcm = ax.pcolor(X,Y,B, data=Z, vmin=minn, vmax=minn, cmap= 'coolwarm')
plt.colorbar(pcm)

`with the pcm and plt.colorbar(pcm) lines hashed I am able to generate a 
coloured surface plot`

plt.title('Total Resistance Of Circuit with Three Components')
ax.set_xlabel('Component One Resistance')
ax.set_ylabel('Component Two Resistance')
ax.set_zlabel('Component Three Resistance')
plt.show()


`without the pcm and pltcolorbar(pcm) lines hashed I get the following 
error`


IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis 
(`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices


`I expect to see a 3d surface plot with a colorbar to the right of the 
plot where blue is for the lowest values and red for the highest values 
but instead my output is the surface plot with none of the labels when 
the pcm and plt lines are hashed`
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6601210/4932316) answer and the comments underneath, following is one way to get it work

```
surf = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,B, rstride=1,cstride=1,
               facecolors=fcolors, vmin=minn,vmax=maxx, shade=False)
m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='coolwarm', norm=surf.norm)
m.set_array(B)
plt.colorbar(m)
```

[image]

Comment: I got an error saying `NameError: name 'coolwarm' is not defined`. So then I tried `cmap=cm.coolwarm`, where `import matplotlib.cm as cm`.