# adding color-bar to 3D scatter plot fails on Linux server while succeed on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, linux, matplotlib

I have the following function:

```
def plotTemperatureGradient(temp_mat, file_name):
    xs, ys, zs = temp_mat.shape
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    X, Y, Z = np.mgrid[:xs, :ys, :zs]
    faltten_data = temp_mat.ravel().astype(np.float16)
    color_map = np.zeros((faltten_data.shape[0], 4))
    # map scalars to colors
    minima =  np.min(faltten_data[np.nonzero(faltten_data)])
    maxima = np.max(faltten_data[np.nonzero(faltten_data)])
    norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=minima, vmax=maxima, clip=True)
    mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap='jet')
    rgba = mapper.to_rgba(faltten_data)

    color_map[:,0:3] = rgba[:, 0:3]
    color_map[:,3] = np.where(faltten_data > 0, 0.07, 0)
    p = ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=color_map.astype(np.float16))
    ax.set_xlabel('X position [Arb.]')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y position [Arb.]')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z position [Arb.]')
    c_bar = plt.colorbar(mapper, cmap='jet')
    c_bar.set_label('Temp [K]')
    # plt.title(title)
    plt.savefig(file_name)
    plt.close(fig)
    print("Exported Temperature Gradient")
    return
```

which gets a 3D numpy array and plots it using `scatter` and produce the following on Windows:

[image]

When I run the same code on a Linux server, as part of a script, it fails and give me the following errors:

> plotTemperatureGradient(temp_domain, 'test.png')   File "CloudDomainCreate.py", line 151, in plotTemperatureGradient
>       c_bar = plt.colorbar(mapper, cmap='jet')   File "/apps/RH7U2/gnu/python/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
>   line 2100, in colorbar
>       ret = gcf().colorbar(mappable, cax = cax, ax=ax, **kw)   File "/apps/RH7U2/gnu/python/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py",
>   line 2129, in colorbar
>       cb = cbar.colorbar_factory(cax, mappable, **cb_kw)   File "/apps/RH7U2/gnu/python/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py",
>   line 1567, in colorbar_factory
>       cb = Colorbar(cax, mappable, **kwargs)   File "/apps/RH7U2/gnu/python/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py",
>   line 1073, in **init**
>       mappable.autoscale_None()   File "/apps/RH7U2/gnu/python/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cm.py",
>   line 374, in autoscale_None
>       raise TypeError('You must first set_array for mappable') TypeError: You must first set_array for mappable

I could not find a way to fix it, I also tried following this question: [Colorbar for matplotlib plot_surface command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600579/colorbar-for-matplotlib-plot-surface-command) but with no success.

Would appreciate some help

Comment: Can you compare and tell us the versions of python and matplotlib installed on the two machines?

Answer (score 1):

The version where it works is newer than the one where it doesn't. 
In older versions you need to set the array manually,

```
mapper.set_array([])
```

Comment: I could not find a documentation that address this issue, can you refer me to one for the future

Comment: Looking closer, the whole approach seems to be wrong. You can forget about mapper/ScalarMappable and stuff, and just use a colorbar for the scatter directly.

Comment: I used the mapper and all because I wanted to avoid plotting all the points not relevant for the "cube"; I tried other method but with no success. so I used mapper and then for points I didn't want to appear I set the `alpha` to 0; Do you think there is another approach?

Comment: There would be other approaches, but if you have one that works, don't put more effort in it. `mapper.set_array([])` is future-proof, so you can have that line in your code, independent which version you use.