# When adding Colorbar for a Matplotlib Tricontourf: "TypeError: You must first set_array for mappable" (MacOS has this problem, Win10 No Problem)

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, contour, colorbar

I have a np.array of a few columns recording many parameters and the result derived from these parameters. Now I am trying to make a contour plot of 2 parameters to see their effect on the result.

```
param_1 = record[:,5]
param_2 = record[:,6]
result = record[:,3]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
cntr = ax.tricontourf(param_1, param_2, result, levels=15, cmap=cm.jet)
print(cntr.cvalues.min())
print(cntr.cvalues.max())
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=cntr.cvalues.min(),vmax=cntr.cvalues.max())
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cm.jet)
print(sm)
fig.colorbar(sm, ticks=cntr.levels)
```

Then the TypeError jumps out:

```
0.0675
0.2925
<matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable object at 0x1274adbe0>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-1f1b3d95dbe5> in <module>
      9 sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cm.jet)
     10 print(sm)
---> 11 fig.colorbar(sm, ticks=cntr.levels)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in colorbar(self, mappable, cax, ax, use_gridspec, **kw)
   2127                              'panchor']
   2128         cb_kw = {k: v for k, v in kw.items() if k not in NON_COLORBAR_KEYS}
-> 2129         cb = cbar.colorbar_factory(cax, mappable, **cb_kw)
   2130 
   2131         self.sca(current_ax)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py in colorbar_factory(cax, mappable, **kwargs)
   1564         cb = ColorbarPatch(cax, mappable, **kwargs)
   1565     else:
-> 1566         cb = Colorbar(cax, mappable, **kwargs)
   1567 
   1568     cid = mappable.callbacksSM.connect('changed', cb.on_mappable_changed)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py in __init__(self, ax, mappable, **kw)
   1070         # Ensure the given mappable's norm has appropriate vmin and vmax set
   1071         # even if mappable.draw has not yet been called.
-> 1072         mappable.autoscale_None()
   1073 
   1074         self.mappable = mappable

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cm.py in autoscale_None(self)
    372         """
    373         if self._A is None:
--> 374             raise TypeError('You must first set_array for mappable')
    375         self.norm.autoscale_None(self._A)
    376         self.changed()

TypeError: You must first set_array for mappable})
```

However, with the same data and code, I can make it under Windows10. It seems the problem is the OS (now is in MacOS).

Also, I found a similar question asked a few month ago:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59303394/adding-color-bar-to-3d-scatter-plot-fails-on-linux-server-while-succeed-on-windo)

Comment: Did you consider the answer to the question you linked? It seems you have an older version of matplotlib on your MacOS machine that your windows machine. Did you try adding a line `sm.set_array([])` as suggested in the linked Q&A?

Comment: I believe matplotlib v3.1.0 is the version where this behaviour changed and you no longer need to `set_array`

Comment: @tmdavison Thank you! Indeed, it is due to the version of matplotlib. The version is  v3.0.3 and by adding `sm.set_array([])` the problem is solved. In v3.3.1, it is OK. Shame, I asked a duplicate question...